# how to search for places nearby google api python

Tags: python, api, google-maps

Currently, when I search for businesses near a certain point in google api, I specify a business type, as per https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

I use:

```
gmaps.places_nearby(lat, long, type='specific business type', radius)
```

how do I search for ALL places nearby that returns all business types? I have tried  [Google Places Nearby Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156024/google-places-nearby-search), [google map api nearby place search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437643/google-map-api-nearby-place-search), and [Find Places Nearby in Google Maps using Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265882/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-api) but none seem to help.

I tried:

```
gmaps.nearbySearch(location, radius)
```

but get an error:

```
'Client' object has no attribute 'nearbySearch'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the method was to not specify a type, and then to extract the type via the resulting json

```
gmaps.places_nearby(lat, long, radius)

types = ('|'.join(types))
```